# Responsive multi level menu

Tags: jquery, html, css, accordion

I've been trying to put together a responsive accordion style multi level menu with parts from various tutorials. The issue I'm having is using slideToggle on the secondary list in the responsive view, nothing seems to happen and I don't see any console errors.

I've set up a JS Fiddle so you can easily look at it here: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X88vM/)

Any help on this is much appreciated, thanks.

HTML

```
<nav class="clearfix">
    <a href="#" id="pull">Menu</a>
    <ul class="clearfix" id="TopLevel-List">
        <li><a href="#" id="trigger_Nested-0">Nav 1</a>
            <ul class="clearfix" id="Nested-0">
                <li><a href="#">Ad Hoc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Drill Down</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ranking Report</a></li>
            </ul>     
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 3</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >Ad Hoc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Drill Down</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ranking Report</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 4</a>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" >Ad Hoc</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Drill Down</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ranking Report</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 5</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Nav 6</a></li>  
    </ul>
</nav>
```

jQuery

```
$(function() {
    var pull    = $('#pull');
    menu        = $('nav ul');
    menuHeight  = menu.height();

    $(pull).on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        menu.slideToggle();
    });

    $(window).resize(function(){
        var w = $(window).width();
        if(w > 320 && menu.is(':hidden')) {
            menu.removeAttr('style');
        }
    });
});

$(function(){
    $("ul[id|=Nested]").hide();

    $("a[id|=trigger_Nested]").click(function() {
        $(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle("fast");
        return false;
    });
});
```

Comment: try the light weight and multilevel responsive menu -> github.com/hidaytrahman/hr-navigation-responsive-menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/X88vM/3/

The reason nothing happens is that you have the `li` display set to `none` in the css.

Under `@media screen and (max-width: 600px)` change the display to block:

```
nav li ul li    {
          display: block;
          height: auto;                                 
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          width:100px;                      
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems only Nav 1 was supposed to have the sliding behavior so I focused on that one.

It didn't appear to do anything because the `li` was set to `display:none`. The `ul` itself had a height of zero as a result of that and when you toggle the slide, it would be sliding to and from a height of zero which does nothing.

http://jsfiddle.net/X88vM/2/

I added a line to show the `li` when the `ul` is supposed to expand.

```
          $("a[id|=trigger_Nested]").click(function() {
            $(this).siblings ('ul').find ('li').show (); //this line i added
            $(this).siblings("ul").slideToggle("fast");

            return false;
          });
```

**EDIT**

The above was just to show you the bare minimum of why your slide toggle wasn't working. If you want the solution to be more generalized/better you should do this instead http://jsfiddle.net/X88vM/4/:

```
     nav li ul li   {
          /*display: none;*/  //comment out this line
          height: auto;                                 
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          width:100px;                      
     }

#Nested-0 {  //add this new rule
    display:none;
}
```

and in your code

```
menu        = $('#TopLevel-List');  //change to this selector instead
```

I find it strange to mix dropdowns and accordions in the same menu.

Comment: That's great, thanks. The only problem I have now is there seems to be a glitch in how the accordion opens on the secondary list the first time you click. I tried adding position:relative to the parent container but didn't seem to work?